# What will be the easiest java code for a file upload in server

Tags: java, file-upload, upload

I am using following PHP code to upload file from client side to server with some conditions.
- One file at a time and file size less than 35mb.
- File only support "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "wav", "mp3" format.
- Every file must upload in a only 10 digit's name folder, given by client during file's upload (if this folder name already present,the file will automatically upload inside the present folder, without making any new folder)

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
 if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
  $errors= array();
  $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
  $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];   
  $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

  $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png","wav","mp3");   
  if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
   $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
  }
  if($file_size > 34097152){
  $errors[]='File size must be exactly 34 MB';
  }    
  if(empty($errors)==true){
   $pinCode = $_POST['pinc'].".".$file_ext;
   if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$_POST['pinc']."/".$file_name))
   {
/*     if(rename("mobile/".$file_name,"mobile/".$mobile number))*/
     echo "Success";
   }
   else
   {
   if (mkdir($_POST['pinc'])) {
                      move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$_POST['pinc']."/".$file_name);
             } else
             {
                      die('Failed to create folders...'); 
              }

   }
  }else{
   print_r($errors);
  }
 }
?>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="30%" align="right"><strong>mobilenumber </strong></td>
    <td width="22%"><input type="text" name="pinc" value="" /></td>
    <td width="48%">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="file" name="image" />
</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit"/></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**I try to make it in Java + Http.** I am not so good at java but still I worked out few parts (you can see it in [jsfiddle.net/sNxh8](http://jsfiddle.net/sNxh8/)) but get trap where I have to submit the form after checking the 3 conditions. A little guideline will be appreciated. Thanks in advance
The result will be like this (http:/ /www.sitename.com/mobile/client's_10_digits_folder_name/file.mp3).

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a servlet.Create a servlet and check this one out.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm

Comment: @[Soumyadeep Ganguly](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2681132/soumyadeep-ganguly) can you please guide me in details, I am not so good in java or JSP.

Comment: start with eclipse->file->dynamic web project.After that go to the project java resources then under src create a servlet name it UploadServlet .Then copy the UploadServlet class given in that link.Deploy the project on any server and u r done.